# debootstrap Couldn't find these debs: lxc

Tags: lxc, debootstrap

I'm trying to follow along to a guide to creating an unprivileged lxc container on Ubuntu.  According to the instructions, I should run:

```
debootstrap --include=lxc eoan rootfs
```

But when I run that, I get the following output:

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32)
I: Retrieving Packages 
I: Validating Packages 
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Checking component main on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu...
E: Couldn't find these debs: lxc
```

I checked and it looks like the "lxc" package is available at the mirror.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, or how debootstrap finds packages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I failed to enable other sources:

```
debootstrap --components=main,restricted,universe --include=lxc eoan rootfs
```